# Reactjs dynamic optgroup with options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, optgroup

I'm trying to map over an array and create a select with optgroups and then its opts. However the following code will only output the optgroup;

```
<select name="clients">
  {this.props.clients &&
    this.props.clients.length > 0 &&
    this.props.clients.map((e, key) => {
      return (
        <optgroup key={key} label={e.name}>
          {e.projects.map((project, projectKey) => {
            <option key={projectKey} value={project.id}>
              {project.name}
            </option>;
          })}
        </optgroup>
      );
    })}
</select>
```

Any ideas how I can get the options output too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your inner `map()` function is not returning any object. Add `return` just before your `<option>` element.

```
<select name="clients">
    {this.props.clients && this.props.clients.length > 0 && this.props.clients.map((e, key) => {
        return <optgroup key={key} label={e.name}>
            {e.projects.map((project,projectKey) => {
                return <option key={projectKey} value={project.id}>{project.name}</option>
            })}
        </optgroup>;
    })}
</select>
```

Comment: Or optionally one can replace `e.projects.map((project,projectKey) => {... return ...}` with `e.projects.map((project,projectKey) => (...)` without a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok check it out. I have the following two files in my React project. The first already contains some dummy state data for example, calls my endpoint and populates my state, and creates an instance of my Dropdown component.

In my fetch I also have some logic to dynamically create category groups, to be used in my optgroup definition. Also is a check to make sure I don't include any profession twice, namely profession_id #2.

```
state = {
    users: [{user_id: 0, user_name:"John", profession_id: 1, profession:"Developer"},
            {user_id: 1, user_name:"Bob", profession_id: 2, profession:"Janitor"},
            {user_id: 2, user_name:"Tony", profession_id: 2, profession:"Janitor"},
            {user_id: 3, user_name:"Steve", profession_id: 3, profession:"Electrician"}
    ],
    categories: [{prof_id: 1, prof_name:"Developer"},
                 {prof_id: 2, prof_name:"Janitor"},
                 {prof_id: 3, prof_name:"Electrician"}
    ]
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchUsers();
}

fetchUsers = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:9999/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        json.forEach(user => {
            this.setState({ users: [...this.state.users, user] });

            if (!this.state.categories.some(
            category => category.prof_id == user.profession_id)) {
                let optionGroupData = {
                    prof_id: user.profession_id,
                    prof_name: user.profession_name
                }
                this.setState({ 
                    categories: [...this.state.categories, optionGroupData] 
                });
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

render(){
    return(
        <Dropdown options={this.state.users} optionGroups={this.state.categories}/>
    )
}
```

Dropdown.js
Here is the stateless definition for a dropdown component. All the data gets passed from the first file through the Dropdown props.

Inside I created my select tags, and within them I am first iterating through my categories array to render the optgroup. For the first loop through, it renders the optgroup and then iterates through my users. If the user's profession id matches the optgroup id, I render the option with the data I want to display in the dropdown.

```
render(){
    return(
        <select>
            this.props.optionGroups.map(optionGroup => {
                return (
                    <optgroup key={optionGroup.prof_id} label={optionGroup.prof_name}>
                        {this.props.options.map(option => {
                            if(option.profession_id == optionGroup.prof_id){
                                return(
                                    <option key={option.profession_id} value={option.id}> 
                                        {option.user_name}
                                    </option>
                                )
                            }
                        })}
                    </optgroup>
                )
            }
        </select>
    )
}
```